# 1980s TV show with teenage alien boy with PSI powers hiding on Earth

Tags: story-identification, tv

In the early 1980s there was a U.S. TV show aired on Dutch television that I want to track down. (Show might be from late 1970s; it usually took a few years before things showed on Dutch TV back then.)

I never saw much of it as it aired in mid-afternoon, before I could get home from school. As I recall it was only 1 season, maybe not even a whole season.

The main character is a 15 or 16-year-old teenage boy who is actually an alien prince. After a coup/war on his home planet killed his father (which took place when he was very young), he was brought to Earth by his mother (or nanny, I never figured out the actual relation).

He tries to live a normal life with his mother (or nanny posing as mother), but agents from the enemy alien government are still looking for him. Some Earth government agencies are also interested in him because of his psi powers that develop as he grows older. I recall he had telekinesis, telepathy and some form of remote sensing. The "mother" doesn't have any special powers, if I recall correctly.

The U.S. Air Force knows about his presence and he has an Air Force liaison officer (a black guy if I remember correctly, but I may be mixing this up with "Chappy" from the Iron Eagle movies). Occasionally the Air Force asks him to use his psi talents for a Specials Ops sort of thing.

In the TV show he has a high-school sweetheart who eventually discovers his secret and gets involved in his adventures too.

I vaguely recall that the young man has a mark on his forehead (possibly star-shaped) that is normally invisible but that can glow.  (When he uses his psi powers?)  This mark is the sign that he is the true heir to his fathers kingdom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [*The Powers of Matthew Star*](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/powers_of_matthew_star_the) (1982-83).

---

**The main character is a 15 or 16-year-old teenage boy who is actually an alien prince.  After a coup/war on his home planet killed his father (which took place when he was very young), he was brought to Earth by his mother (or nanny, I never figured out the actual relation).**

> Matthew Star (Barton) is in reality the **alien prince** E'Hawke from the twelve-lightyears-distant planet Quadris, hiding on Earth from rebel forces which have **overthrown the royal family.**

This actor was about 16 when the show started.

**The U.S. Air Force knows about his presence and he has an Air Force liaison officer (a black guy...I may be mixing this up with "Chappy" from the Iron Eagle movies)**

> He is accompanied by his Guardian D'Hai, alias Walt Shepherd (Gossett).

[The actor for this character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Gossett_Jr.), Louis Gosset Jr., [played Chappy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Gossett_Jr.#Filmography).<sup>1</sup>

**In the TV show he has a high-school sweetheart who eventually discovers his secret and gets involved in his adventures too.**

> At Crestridge High School, setting of the first half of the season, Star masquerades as a student while Shepherd is a science teacher; Pam Elliot (Steel) is **Matthew's girlfriend**...

Note that, as far as is mentioned, she doesn't know his secret.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Thanks to eshier for pointing this out [in the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213529/1980s-tv-show-with-teenage-alien-boy-with-psi-powers-hiding-on-earth/213530#comment583131_213530)</sub>

<sub>note: emphasis mine on all quotes</sub>

Comment: @Tonny The Guardian was played by Louis Gossett, Jr. who had a movie out around the same time where he was an air force pilot ([Iron Eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Eagle))  That may account for that detail.

Comment: @Tonny  Also, the [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Powers_of_Matthew_Star) indludes:  "General Tucker (John Crawford), an Air Force officer specializing in extraterrestrial investigations, had tracked the two of them across the country ..., he enlisted their specialized aid in solving monumental problems." & "The series took a sudden turn from a dramatic adventure series to a by-the-book adventure series, with Walt and Matthew having to deal with government assignments."

Comment: @eshier No wonder I mixed up the guardian  and the general :-)

Comment: This is it. I now recognize the name Matthew Star.