# Show with a human/maybe alien with powers (from the '90s, I think)

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

In the show there is this guy and he has abilities...not really like showy powers. For example he can just open a locked door without picking it. He just turns the handle and it's open kind of deal.

I think he knows he's from another planet. He looks up to a star and has a birthmark, I think. He is not human, but looks human. He does not have a good relationship with his mother.

And in one episode there was a case about giving kids juice boxes that had some blood in it or something. The guy is like a sociopath, really, I guess due to his nature, but he wants to help people.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I know you said you think this is from the '90s, but in roughly which year did you actually watch it? Also, roughly how old did the character appear to be? And did he go to school, or have a job?

Comment: Live action show or animated? In English or another language?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [The Powers Of Matthew Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Powers_of_Matthew_Star).

The answer to  [this earlier question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213529/1980s-tv-show-with-teenage-alien-boy-with-psi-powers-hiding-on-earth?rq=1).

**In the show there is this guy and he has abilities...not really like showy powers.**

From wiki

> Matthew's powers during this season were mainly telekinetic, being able to move objects with the power of his mind. This power was illustrated in the opening credits as moving a book back into a slot on a bookshelf. In episodes, he used telekinesis to manipulate a football, and raise rocks that had buried an experimental Air Force flying unit and then its simulation.

**I think he knows he's from another planet.**

From Wiki

> It starred Peter Barton as the title character, the alien prince Matthew "E'Hawke" Star of the planet Quadris, who used his powers to fight crime.

**He looks up to a star and has a birthmark, I think.**

From the previous thread.

> I vaguely recall that the young man has a mark on his forehead (possibly star-shaped) that is normally invisible but that can glow. (When he uses his psi powers?) This mark is the sign that he is the true heir to his fathers kingdom.

**He does not have a good relationship with his mother.**

From Wiki

> In the episode "Mother," a strange carnival gypsy is revealed to be Matthew's mother, Nadra, who had been traveling the galaxy and hiding from assassins. This reunion was bittersweet; due to Nadra's health problems, she was forced to leave Crestridge for an undisclosed location at a higher elevation.

Comment: There are reviews of all of the episodes (and screenshots) at https://drunktv.net/2019/02/24/the-powers-of-matthew-star-1982-1983-tv-series-review/. Haven't seen anything about juice-boxes.